# How to defer the execution of a python task in tornado?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

I've got an internet site running on tornado, with video features (convert, cut, merge).

The video traitement is quite long, so i want to move it to another python process, and keep the tornado process as light as possible.

I use the mongo db for commun db functionalities, synchronously as the db will stay light.

Comment: I modified the question (in a good way i hope)

Comment: It is somewhat short now, but at least the recommendation part is gone, which is definitely an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Use Celery to defer tasks

video.py:

```
@task
def convert(video):
  ...
```

tornadoserver.py

```
import video
...
def get(self):
    paramvideo=...
    convert.delay(paramvideo)
    ...
```

Comment: https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery allows to call tasks in a non-blocking way

Answer (score 0):

Use mongo to defer task

video.py:

```
def convert():
    ...
db = Connection().my_db
cursor = db.tasks.find(tailable=True)
while cursor.alive:
    try:
        next = cursor.next()
        if next.t=='convert':
           convert(next.d)
    except StopIteration:
        time.sleep(1)
```

tornadoserver.py

```
...
def get(self):
    ...
    paramvideo=...
    conn.tasks.insert({t:'convert',d:paramvideo})
```